# Porting socket program to mac from pc and get a Permission denied when creating a socket

Tags: java, macos, sockets

I'm trying to port my project to the mac from a pc.
When executing

```
server = new ServerSocket(80);
```

A exception gets thrown saying Permission denied. I'm login as a admin.

Comment: Can you post the whole stack trace of the exception being thrown ?

Comment: Are you using `sudo` to start the JVM?

Comment: By "login as a admin", do you mean logged as `root` or logged as an user with admin privileges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On every major OS other than Windows, you can't bind to port 80 unless you're root. Not just an admin user -- root.

On the Mac, port 80 may also already be in use by the built-in web server (Apache) if that's enabled.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for answering my question ok I can use another port numb.  Silly question, if I build the program under the root user account.  How would some one install the PROGRAM ON A MAC (I'm a pc person just starting to use a mac so I did not have to deal with these issues before) Ted

Answer (score 0):

Probably there's a restriction using that port. Try running it with an **uncommon port number**.

Also try this to check which ports  are available for proper use or not :

```
ServerSocket serversocket = null;

    try {
        serversocket = new ServerSocket(i);
        serversocket.close();
        System.out.println(i + " Available");
    } catch (BindException ex) {
        System.out.println(i + " Unavailable");
    }
}
```

Comment: Port in use doesn't cause 'Permission denied'.

Answer (score 0):

The "Permission denied" message implies that your user does not have the necessary permissions to bind a socket to that port. On Unix-based OSes, ports lower than 1024 can only be bound by the `root` user. Probably a similar restriction also applies to Windows - does your Windows user have administrator permissions?

If your user did have permissions and there was another service running at port 80, such as Apache, you'd  get an "Address already in use" message.